# Can we build search filter or other specialized view models with AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

We have been using AutoMapper to map DTO or view models with entity (domain) models. But there are some types of view models that are built from the entity without a 1 to 1 matching.

For example, on a search page,

- the options for a select control are collected from the values in the entity model.
- the date range for the datepicker will be decided by the min and max dates retrieved from the entity.
- some value range options are just manually created.

```
var model = new FilterOptionsModel
        {
            Organizations = all.Select(t => t.Organization.Name).Distinct(),
            Locations = all.Select(t => t.Location.Name).Distinct(),
            Types = all.Select(t => t.Type).Distinct(),   
            MinDate = all.Select(t => t.Date).Min(),
            MaxDate = all.Select(t => t.Date).Max(),
            NumberGroups = new[] { "All", "1 ~ 10", ">10" }
        };
```

My question is, is it possible to create this kind of view model with AutoMapper? Or, are we asking too much for it?

---

Update:

Here is what I've got so far, thanks to Andrew Whitaker's answer.

```
        Mapper.CreateMap<Tournament, FilterOptionsModel>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Organizations,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Organization.Name.Distinct()))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Locations,
                opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Location.Name.Distinct()));
```

As mentioned in the comments, I find no `Select` link Linq method available on `src` in the lambda expression.

But for `MinDate` and `MaxDate`, I still haven't figure out how to do the MapFrom. Any suggestions?

Comment: I just cannot think of a better title. Pls feel free to edit if you have a better one. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use AutoMapper for this? AutoMapper is intended to avoid repetitive code when making simple, obvious mappings between objects that are practically the same. It seems like you just need a *Mapper*--without the "Auto" part.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior. I'm just... curious! So I guess your answer is a "no" - it is not something AutoMapper would handle, isn't it?

Comment: I'm sure it *can* be done. It's just not what AutoMapper is *for*. It's like asking how to use mail-merge to write a letter to one person. The code you've provided is clear, concise, and specific. Stick it someplace where it can be reused, and you're in good shape. AutoMapper just adds complexity for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<MyObject>, FilterOptionsModel>()
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Organizations,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Select(t => t.OrganizationUnit.Name).Distinct())
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.Locations,
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Select(t => t.Location.Name).Distinct())
    /* etc */
    .ForMember(
        dest => dest.NumberGroups,
        opt => opt.UseValue(new[] { "All", "1 ~ 10", ">10" }));
```

Usage:

```
var all = /* */;

Mapper.Map<FilterOptionsViewModel>(all);
```

Comment: How come I don't have `Select` method for `src=>src`?

Comment: You might need `@using Linq;`

Comment: Are you sure @Darren? After I added the reference `using System.Linq;`, still nothing happens. Can we really LINQ against the `src` in AutoMapper?

Comment: I find the `Select` may not be necessary. `.ForMember(dest => dest.Locations,
                    opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Location.Name.Distinct()))`